# ffmpeg fully html 5 converion supported

Tags: ffmpeg, html5

I need to know about library that required for ffmpeg for convert any format of audio and video for supported following format to have best configuration to convert audio and video files for html5 formats.

I need for support **mp3** and **ogg** for audio files.

Also need for support **FLV**, **H.264**, **Ogg Theora** and **VP8 (WebM)** for video files.

I'm using debian also using deb-multimedia repository.

I need list of packages required for this formats(any format to this formats). also any configuration for install from package management or compile via latest ffmpeg repository.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tried googling? "ffmpeg webm" found this on the 2nd hit http://blog.pcode.nl/2010/10/17/encoding-webm-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: @Tim O'Connor: That link suggests copying the libvpx preset if not present. This is not recommended due to syntax/feature changes and additions. FFmpeg comes with presets, but they should not be mixed among different versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/
It's a static ffmpeg build, so you can just download and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [WebM project itself](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mainconcept.com/, http://www.elecard.com/, http://www.webmproject.org/, http://www.theora.org/, http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Basically you need to check what are your source files first. If it's interlaced like TV, you will need deinterlacer filter used. If you want to transcode from DVD, ffmpeg has the worst quality of MPEG-2 decode.
You need to check your output profiles too. Apart from that, you will need demuxers (MP4, MPEG-2 TS) and muxers, AAC audio for H.264, MP4 hinted files for seeking (MP4Box). Autocropping maybe, subtitling might be useful. There is plenty of components really depends on your files and your website, if it's for mobile and HD TV, or just Desktop website or all of them.